# Child theme functions.php file change database entries

Tags: php, database, child-theme, variables, constants

I'm sure my title is not the correct terminology.  I will do my best to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.  Years ago I spent countless hours customizing a theme.  I was finally forced to update my theme and rather than putting all those customizations back, I would like to do this through the child theme.

I've created my child theme with the `style.css` and `functions.php` files.  My `functions.php` file is empty.

How do I alter multiple `.css` files through the child theme?  I also need to change the `main-stylesheet.css` file.

There is a file `dynamic-css.php` that has the following line:

```
$bg_texture_header = get_option(THEME_NAME."_bg_texture_header");
```

I could of course change the image file in `THEME_NAME/images/_bg_texture_header` which could be lost at the next upgrade.

I went into the database and changed the option_value from `main-header-wrapper-bg.jpg` to `uploads/main-header-wrapper-bg.jpg`. This worked, I need to do this for several files.  How can I make this change from Child Theme `functions.php`?

I'm a newbie at php, outside of deleting lines or copy and pasting lines.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to change anything in the database. If you've set up your child theme correctly, and it appears in the list of installed themes, activating that child theme, should make any updates necessary. The customizations you made back in the day should go in the child functions.php and child style.css. As long as the function names and class names haven't been changed in the original the child theme files should overwrite the parent theme.

Comment: I found a style.php file that I was able to change so when I go into the theme control panel I can make most of my changes there.  This took care of the db issues.  I'm assuming I just copy the style.php file to my child theme and then make the changes in the child theme.  I still don't know how to edit multiple css files with the child theme?  Thank you for your help.